# Hours and minutes between 2 incorrectly formatted datetimes

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, type-conversion

So i have some timestamps in a DB and i want to get the hours and minutes difference from them

The problem is the timestamp portion is formatted incorrectly where the hour is always 12 and the minutes portion is actually the hours and the seconds is actually the minutes.

Example DB timestamp: 10/1/2020 12:08:52 AM

So in the above example the time is actually 8:52 AM not 12:08 AM

How can i convert this datetime to something i can use in order to calculate the difference in minutes and hours between these 2 oddly formatted timestamps?

My ideal end goal is something that displays the difference in the HH:MM format

EDIT: the timestamps in oracle actually look like below, and in this eaxmple the 12 means nothing and 18 is actually the hours.

Example of what I'm looking for:

01-OCT-20 12.18.44.000000000 AM - 01-OCT-20 12.12.42.000000000 AM

Output: 06:02 . so the timespan would be 6 hours and 2 minutes in this case.

Thanks,

Comment: Why on earth do you store timestamps as **string**? You should convert them to proper `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` data type.

Comment: I beleive they are in the timestamp format, the problem is the hours is defaulted to 12, and the minutes is actually the hours

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your string to an Oracle `date` (resp `timestamp`) with `to_date()` (resp `to_timestamp()`):

```
to_timestamp(mystring, 'dd/mm/yyyy ss:hh12:mi am')
```

Then you can use date arithmetics to compute the difference. Substrating timestamps gives you an interval, which is pretty much what you seem to be looking for, so:

```
to_timestamp(mystring1, 'dd/mm/yyyy ss:hh12:mi am') 
    - to_timestamp(mystring2, 'dd/mm/yyyy ss:hh12:mi am') 
    as myinterval
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

(my default date format is `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'` in Oracle ...)

```
WITH 
indata(sdb) AS (
            SELECT '10/1/2020 12:08:52 AM' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT '10/1/2020 12:08:52 PM' FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  TO_TIMESTAMP(sdb,'dd/mm/yyyy 12:hh:mi AM') AS ts
FROM indata;
-- out          ts          
-- out ---------------------
-- out  2020-01-10 08:52:00
-- out  2020-01-10 20:52:00
```