# incorrect date time format in Oracle DB, convert to hours and minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, converters

Don't ask me why but for some reason we have a date time column that is in the wrong format that I need help converting.

Example timestamp from DB: 01-OCT-20 12.18.44.000000000 AM

In the example above the hours is actually 18 and the minutes is 44.

Not sure how this happened by 12 is the default for everything.  All I want to do is get the difference in HH:MM from 2 timestamps, but I don't know how to convert this properly with the hours being in the minute section and the minutes being in the seconds section.

Example of what I'm looking for:

01-OCT-20 12.18.44.000000000 AM - 01-OCT-20 12.12.42.000000000 AM

Output: 06:02 . so the timespan would be 6 hours and 2 minutes in this case.

Comment: This is quite similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266817/hours-and-minutes-between-2-incorrectly-formatted-datetimes). Did you check the answer that you received there?

Comment: Yes I was actually in the process of deleting it, i thought the way i worded the question was not done well so i rewrote it.  I tried the answers and none of them worked so i thought simplifying what i wanted would help.

Comment: Just realized i cant delete posts lol

Comment: The difference between `2020-10-01 00:18:44` and `2020-10-01 18:44:00` (with minutes mapped to hours and seconds mapped to minutes) is 18 hours, 25 minutes and 16 seconds. How do you calculate 6 hours and 2 minutes? (I also suggest that you work with a 24 hour clock rather than a 12 hour clock as that may have contributed to the confusion.)

Comment: "Format" means how it's displayed, like you can display the same number as `1.23` or `01.230` etc. Those are formats. The *actual stored value* is an internal binary value that you can't read, and any answer will depend very much on the column definition (`varchar2(30)`, `timestamp with local timezone`, `date` and so on). So, is the question about the format, or the value, and how is the column defined?

Comment: @MT0 Not sure where you got that first timestamp from, see my example for what im looking for. 01-OCT-20 12.18.44.000000000 AM - 01-OCT-20 12.12.42.000000000 AM.  both columns timestamps formats are wrong where the hours is actually in the minutes field.

Comment: `01-OCT-20 12.18.44.000000000 AM` uses the 12 hour clock. In the 24 hour clock the same time is `2020-10-01 00:18:44`.

Answer (score 0):

> In the example above the hours is actually 18 and the minutes is 44.
>
> Not sure how this happened by 12 is the default for everything. All I want to do is get the difference in HH:MM from 2 timestamps, but I don't know how to convert this properly with the hours being in the minute section and the minutes being in the seconds section.

- To convert minutes to hours, you need to multiply by 60.
- To convert seconds to minutes, you also need to multiply by 60.
- So, if you want to convert the time part of the correct value then you take the time since midnight and multiply it all by 60.
- If you want to get the difference between the current and correct time (after multiplying by 60) then you want to subtract the current time (which can be simplified to just multiplying by 59).

So to get the time difference you can use:

```sql
SELECT (value - TRUNC(value))*59 AS difference,
       value + (value - TRUNC(value))*59 AS updated_value
FROM   table_name;
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( '01-OCT-20 12.18.44.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF9 AM' ) FROM DUAL
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> DIFFERENCE                    | UPDATED_VALUE             
> :---------------------------- | :-------------------------
> +000000000 18:25:16.000000000 | 2020-10-01 18:44:00.000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dfdb42d8ddf1a0940cb89ff41a00710f)*

If you want to compare two wrong values just subtract one timestamp from the other and multiply by 60 (assuming that the hour will always be `12 AM` or `00` in the 24 hour clock):

```sql
SELECT (value1 - value2) * 60 AS difference,
       value1,
       value1 + (value1 - TRUNC(value1))*59 AS updated_value1,
       value2,
       value2 + (value2 - TRUNC(value2))*59 AS updated_value2
FROM   table_name;
```

So, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value1, value2 ) AS
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( '01-OCT-20 12.18.44.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF9 AM' ),
       TO_TIMESTAMP( '01-OCT-20 12.12.42.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF9 AM' )
FROM DUAL
```

The output is:

> ```
> DIFFERENCE                    | VALUE1                     | UPDATED_VALUE1             | VALUE2                     | UPDATED_VALUE2            
> :---------------------------- | :------------------------- | :------------------------- | :------------------------- | :-------------------------
> +000000000 06:02:00.000000000 | 2020-10-01 00:18:44.000000 | 2020-10-01 18:44:00.000000 | 2020-10-01 00:12:42.000000 | 2020-10-01 12:42:00.000000
> ```

Which gives the difference as 6 hours and 2 minutes.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9fa710bdc2105978c1cdf3a6c9eb95df)*